# Flutter : Location Package Error meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist

Tags: flutter, dart

**Describe the bug**
I want Installing Location Package with version ^2.3.5 But I get message error like this on my device :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GoogleApiAvailabilityCache.getClientAvailability(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.zab(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

#### My Configuration

**Android -> build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    // ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**Android -> App -> build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "id.zeffry.great_place_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="id.zeffry.great_place_app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="great_place_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**I'm really sure have added meta tag google service like this in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

**Tested on:**
 - Android, API Level 24 Nougat using real device

Can you help me with this error ?

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You placed the tag inside of `<Activity>`. It should be within `<Application>` instead:

```xml
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="great_place_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <!-- here -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity ...>
           ...
        </activity>
    </application>
```

If you use reference to resource `@integer/google_play_services_version`, make sure you have this value in resources or just replace the reference with your key.

To place value in resources, create .xml file in /res/values:

```xml
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">value</integer>
</resources>
```